# Schema conversion of a BQ table - Change of columns data type

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, pipeline

We are working on a bigdata pipeline automation on GCP and are ingesting some CSV files. To prevent process break at BQ level due to schema we have ingested the first table after converting all columns as 'STRING' type.

Is it gracefully possible in BQ to have the schema conversion on the table just ingested , so that we can change the STRING types to their actual types like INT64, FLOAT , etc.

Is it a good approach?

Answer (score 0):

There is not a way of "changing data type" without refreshing the whole table. You can run a SQL like

```sql
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION myFunctionStringToFloat(x STRING)
AS (
  -- Assuming you have non-trivial logic to safely convert STRING to FLOAT
  -- If you don't, you can just put SAFE_CAST(x AS FLOAT)
);
CREATE OR REPLACE myTable
AS SELECT * EXCEPT(col1), myFunctionStringToFloat(col1) as col1 FROM myTable;
```

You will be charged the scanning of the table though. The other way is to keep your CSV super clean and make sure the table load succeed with FLOAT column.

Comment: Thanks for your response ! Will try this and keep you posted.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the [GCS/BQ transfer service](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-transfer/docs/cloud-storage-transfer) and define your schema ahead. If there are failures you can get notifications.

Comment: Thanks .  We have used similar approach and have predefined schemas to create/load table. So far it has worked.